# Bring back closed Remote Host Window on PHPStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, window, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, remote-host

I accidentally closed ([image: closed]) the remote host window in a project of PHPStorm and i can't get it back.

It isnt in View->Tool Windows.

[image: remote host]

And is also enabled in Plugin Settings Page

Comment: After you add it back using your solution, the view->tool menu gets the option again... weird

Comment: Yeah its so funny!

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Ok I succesfully bring it back by browsing Tools | Deployment | Browse Remote Host :D

Comment: Thank you!   Expected it to be in View->Tool Windows

Answer (score 3):

Please check if the following options are enabled in settings(Ctrl+Alt+S). It goes uncheck if Php Storm crashes. Check the below options and restart the editor. You will layout restored. (sometimes when editor crash and these gets unchecked).

[image: Plugins list]

This works for ver 2017.2.1
Also, check Windows->Store current layout as the default just to make sure in the future you can restore the layout.

Answer (score 0):

It`s helps to me:

1. Go to "Settings"
2. Find "remote host" in Keymap menu
3. Add any keyboard shortcut to this tool
4. Close settings
5. Push this shortcut

Done!

[image]

[image]